# Jquery help adding ajax function to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add the same ajax call that gets triggered when a checkbox is changed to a input field.

Here is the function that I also want to add when the value of the input field is changed:

```
                        $('#left input:checkbox').change(function() {
                                        $('#formcontent').empty().html('<p style="margin-top:20px;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;font-size:14px;">Vent venligst, henter webhosts.</p><p style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:center;"><img src="../images/ajax.gif" /></p>');
                                        var form = $(this).closest('form');
                                        $.ajax({
                                                type: form.attr('method'),
                                                url: form.attr('action'),
                                                data: form.serialize(),
                                                success:function(msg){
                                        $('#formcontent').html(msg);
                        }
        });
```

Here is my slider code. Which updates the input field:

```
                       $("#slider").slider({
    value:'',
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    step: 250,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == $(this).slider('option', 'max')) {
            $(ui.handle).html('Ubegrænset');
            $('#sliderValueplads').val('99999');
        } else {
            $(ui.handle).html(ui.value + ' MB');
            $('#sliderValueplads').val(ui.value);
        }
    }
}).find('a').html($('#slider').slider('value'));



$('#sliderValueplads').val($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="sliderdiv">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" size="30" name="search[prisar_greater_than]" id="sliderValueplads">
</div>
```

I have tried to replace this line in the code:

```
$('#left input:checkbox').change(function() {
```

With this (not working):

```
$('#left input:checkbox', '#sliderdiv input').change(function() {
```

**Update** 
I have tried clean up the code. The problem is that the callpage does not get triggerhed:

```
                                        function callpage() {
$('#formcontent').empty().html('<p style="margin-top:20px;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;font-size:14px;">Vent venligst, henter webhosts.</p><p style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:center;"><img src="../images/ajax.gif" /></p>');
       var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
                 type: form.attr('method'),
                 url: form.attr('action'),
                 data: form.serialize(),
                 success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
                                        }
        $('#left input:checkbox').change(callpage);
```

And I get this error in firebug:

```
missing } after property list [Break ved denne fejl] $('#left input:checkbox').change(callpage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event won't fire on the text box if you change the value via the jQuery code, you'd need to do something like this in your code -

```
$('#sliderValue').trigger('change')
```

to trigger the change event.

Comment: I've set up a simplified working example in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BZJXC/. Is there anything in there that's different from your code?

Comment: I have tried to create a function named callpage. But the function does not get triggerhed: http://pastie.org/2594571

Comment: Try just passing the function name without the `()` - `$('#left input:checkbox').change(callpage);`

Comment: Have tried get this error: missing } after property list
[Break ved denne fejl] $('#left input:checkbox').change(callpage);